# Can i use wildcard for path variable in spring webfilter?

Tags: java, spring

I want to add filter for this path with wildcards /{login}/cart/* in webfilter config Spring application, but wildcard for {login} is not working

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<UserFilter> homeFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<UserFilter> UserFilterBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    UserFilterBean.setFilter(new UserFilter());
    UserFilterBean.addUrlPatterns("/{login}/cart/*");
    return UserFilterBean;
}
```

Comment: You must use a regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Adding more details to @TongChen's comment

Did you try `UserFilterBean.addUrlPatterns("/\\blogin\\b/cart/*");` ?

spring uses AntPathMatcher, please take a look at this complete documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

I am copying text from the same official documentation's examples part:

Examples

```
com/t?st.jsp — matches com/test.jsp but also com/tast.jsp or com/txst.jsp
com/*.jsp — matches all .jsp files in the com directory
com/**/test.jsp — matches all test.jsp files underneath the com path
org/springframework/**/*.jsp — matches all .jsp files underneath the org/springframework path
org/**/servlet/bla.jsp — matches org/springframework/servlet/bla.jsp but also org/springframework/testing/servlet/bla.jsp and org/servlet/bla.jsp
com/{filename:\\w+}.jsp will match com/test.jsp and assign the value test to the filename variable
```

I have not tried this approach till now, I am going purely based on documentation,

Here is additional documentation that says this approach will work for @RequestMapping for sure, but whether it will be applicable to filter or not is something to be tried - 16.3.2.2 URI Template Patterns with Regular Expressions
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex

Example from documentation to handle :

If you want to handle "/spring-web/spring-web-3.0.5.jar" with a regex then this is the solution:

```
@RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]+}-{version:\d\.\d\.\d}.{extension:\.[a-z]}")
  public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {    
    // ...
  }
}
```

Based on all these I am hopeful that `UserFilterBean.addUrlPatterns("/\\blogin\\b/cart/*");` might be a solution for you